# AS3 TCP Socket Lost Packages

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

I have a AS3 TCP Client Socket connection with a OpenFramework Socket Server.
Sometimes the client send about 20 messages in one second, but the server never receive 1 or 2 messages.

Somebody knows if there is a secury way to send my messages with no lost packages?
Am I doing something wrong?

My code looks like this:

```
socket = new Socket(); 
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler); 
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, dataHandler); 

public function send(m:String):void 
{
    socket.writeUTFBytes(m); 
    socket.flush(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server doesn't receive messages? Network combines small messages into one packet and splits big ones. Maybe you just don't read till the end or wait till the full packet comes in?

Comment: Wheres the code to handle policy file?

Comment: Don't see anything you're doing that is obviously wrong, have you tried monitoring the traffic using something like wireshark or the like?  When it comes to lower level network communication that kind of tool is invaluable.  According to the Adobe docs the Socket class is using a TCP channel meaning it shouldn't be dropping anything (if it were UDP dropped messages would make sense but not on top of TCP which should guarantee reliable transmission of a message) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html

Comment: Sure, but I still have lost packages. I searched for a bug in OF, but didn't find anything http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,1489.0.html
I solved my problem by sending a confirmation at the server that received the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead;

```
socket.writeUTFBytes(m + String.fromCharCode(0));
socket.flush();
```